# Find average value from text file

Tags: c++

Suppose i have a text file with ":" as delimiter, how do i find the average value of each column? For e.g. First column will be (3+2+5)/3 and second column will be (61+87)/2 for the third column.

I have tried using getline in while loop, but it seemed more complicated because i think it requires much more than that. I will appreciate if anyone can enlighten me on this. Thanks!

```
Sample text file
================
3:290:61:100:
2:50:
5:346:87:
```

**Current code**

```
void IDS::parseBase() {



string temp = "";
int counting = 0;
int maxEvent = 0;
int noOfLines = 0;
vector<string> baseVector;


ifstream readBaseFile("Base-Data.txt");
ifstream readBaseFileAgain("Base-Data.txt");




while (getline(readBaseFile, temp)) {

    baseVector.push_back(temp);

}
readBaseFile.close();

//Fine the no. of lines
noOfLines =  baseVector.size();

//Find the no. of events
for (int i=0; i<baseVector.size(); i++)
{
    counting = count(baseVector[i].begin(), baseVector[i].end(), ':') - 1;

    if (maxEvent < counting)
    {
        maxEvent = counting;
    }

}


//Store individual events into array    
string a[maxEvent];



while (getline(readBaseFileAgain, temp)) {
    stringstream streamTemp(temp);

    for (int i=0; i<maxEvent; i++)
    {
         getline(streamTemp, temp, ':');
         a[i] += temp + "\n";


    }


}
```

}

Comment: Debug 1st to narrow your problems befor asking here please!

Comment: Read up a bit on how stackoverflow questions are supposed to be. It isn't meant as service for fixing your programming assignments. Answers should have more general application, and usefull for many people.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to give a direct answer to this question because that is not what Stackoverflow is for. We are not here to debug your programs. Instead I will answer what is really your question:

**How do I debug a simple program like this?**

Build your solution one step at a time, verifying that each step works as you expected. I think your problem is that you are trying to do a lot in one go.

1. Write a simple program that doesn't read any files, but where you have hardcoded a line. say: `char line[] = "3:290:61:100:"`. Split this into separate numbers and write out.
2. When that works try to convert each string of a number to an `int` and add them up. Print out the result.
3. Turn your working code into one function taking a line as argument and returning the sum.
4. Your next step is to create a string with multiple lines like this:
   `char text[] = "3:290:61:100:\n"
   "2:50:\n"
   "5:346:87:\n"`
   Get each individual line and reuse the function you created in steep 3.

I hope you see where this is going. Start simple, solve one problem at a time and put each solved subtask into a reusable function. Too often I see people trying to juggle around one large problem.

If you want to use `getline` and similar functions verify that they work the way to think they work by writing very simple programs. Put in `cout` or `printf` statements in your program to output the result of individual stages in your program to verify that your program does what you think it is supposed to.

Comment: +1 The question looks doomed, but nevertheless a good idea answering to arm up the OP with caveman debugging abilities ;) ... May be at least, you'll receive a _panic accept_.